# best way to R&R engine & trans from 2006 chevy express cargo van?

Tags: replacements

2006 Chevy express cargo van. 4.8 engine with PS & AC, auto trans.
455,000 miles and engine needs replaced.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

There’s really only one way to do it. You need to remove the front bumper, headlights, radiator/condenser etc... Remove the radiator support and pull it out the front.

Comment: Unless you want to use a lot of Sawzall blades ;-)